# Is $x \mapsto d(x, A)$ a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a metric space $(X, d)$ and a nonempty closed set $A \subset X$.
Is the map $d_A : X \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto d(x, A)$ a quotient map
when restricted to its image? Note $d(x, A) = \inf\{ d(x, a) : a \in A \}$.

If this is not true, can a counterexample exist in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Some partial results follow.

If $X$ is compact, then $d_{A}$ is closed. This follows 
since, more generally, continuous maps from compact spaces to Hausdorff spaces are closed.

If $X$ has the Heine-Borel property and $A$ is compact then $d_A$ is closed. For $B \subset X$ closed and $y \in \overline{d_A(B)}$ there exist $x_n \in B$ such that $d_{A}(x_n) \to y$. Exercise 27.2b of Munkres 2ed states that since $A$ is compact, $d(x, A) = d(x, a)$ for some $a \in A$. So there exist $a_n \in A$ such that $d(x_n, a_n) \to y$. Since $A$ is compact there exists a subsequence $a_{i_n}$ of $a_n$ such that $a_{i_n} \to a$. Then
$d(x_{i_n}, a) \le d(x_{i_n}, a_{i_n}) + d(a_{i_n}, a)$ for all $n$, and
the right-hand side of this inequality is eventually less than $y + 1$. So $x_{i_n}$ is eventually contained in a closed bounded closed set, and by the Heine-Borel property there is a subsequence $x_{j_n}$ of $x_{i_n}$ such that
$x_{j_n} \to x$. Since $B$ is closed, $x \in B$. Then continuity and the Hausdorff property imply $d_{A}(x) = y$, implying $y \in d_{A}(B)$. So the claim follows. In the general case, is $d_A$ always a closed map when $A$ is compact?

$d_A$ is not generally a closed map, even when $A$ is closed. Consider the case where $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A$ is the $x$-axis. Then $d_A$ maps the graph of the exponential
function to $(0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can fail if $X$ is not connected but the image of $d_A$ is. For example consider $X = (-1, 0] \cup [1, \infty)$ and $A = \{0\}$, with the Euclidean metric $d_A(x) = | x |$. Then $d_A(X) = [0, \infty)$, which has one component, but no pair of points in distinct components of $X$ has been identified.

In the case $X$ is connected, I don’t see an obvious answer.

Comment: Nice example.${}$

Answer (score 2):

For your second question. $A$ is compact doesn't imply $d_A$ is a closed map. Let $X$ be the space of irrational numbers and $A$ be $\sqrt 2$. Then $B=[0,\sqrt 2]\cap X$ is closed in $X$. But $\sqrt 2\notin d_A (B),$ although it belongs to $d_A(X)$. It's easy to see $\sqrt 2\in \overline{d_A(B)}$, hence $d_A(B)$ is not closed.

Comment: The image of $d_A$ is $\{0, 1\}$ if $X$ has more than one point. Then in the subspace topology $\{1\} \subset d_A(X)$ is open.

Comment: @GeoffreySangston Thanks, I've fixed my example.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the following paper and think it adds to the answers given so far.

[Which Connected Spaces Have a Quotient Homeomorphic to an Arc](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6655.pdf)

It gives additional counterexamples. Example 9 is a counterexample in the case that $X$ is connected and locally compact, and $A$ is a point.

There are also some propositions characterizing when certain maps will be quotients. Theorem 5 states

> If $X$ is a connected, locally connected space, $f : X \to [0, 1]$ is a continuous surjection, then $f$ is a quotient.

In particular, this implies $\frac{d_{A}}{d_A + d_B}$ will be a quotient in the case that $X$ is connected, locally connected, and $A, B$ are disjoint closed sets. This gives an Urysohn map from $A$ to $B$ which is a quotient. I'm not immediately sure if $d_A$ will be a quotient but it seems likely.

Comment: It seems your first question is still unanswered: does a counterexample exist in $X=\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Extend Jackson’s example to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by identifying $\mathbb{R}$ with the $x$-axis and letting the new counterexample be the space swept out by rotating his space about the origin through a full rotation. Jackson also showed me this.

Comment: I don't think so. After rotating you get $A$ is equal to the whole $\Bbb R^2$. You mean rotating $(-1,0]\cup[1,\infty)$ around the origin, right? It doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry rotate it by $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Then it's not even closed in $\Bbb R^2$...

Comment: Whoops. I was distracted earlier and understand your point now. Thank you for following-up. I did originally seek a counterexample where $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Note that in this case for any closed $A$ the map $d_A$ maps onto a connected interval or $\{0\}$. I’m a bit busy now but I think that this paper’s proof of theorem 5 can be modified to show that continuous surjections onto a half open interval when the space is connected and locally connected will be quotient maps. This would imply no counterexample $A$ can exist with $X = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Then you got $A=\Bbb R^2- \text{the open ball of radius 1/2 centered at (1/2,0)}$. How is it a counterexample?

Comment: Sorry I'm having a rough time tonight. Yes rotate about the origin $\frac{\pi}{3}$ radians and take $A = \{0\}$.

Comment: It works. But I still want to stay within the requirement that $X=\Bbb R^2$

Comment: I don't think one exists in that case.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm unable to prove it, nor am I able to find any existing proof on the internet.

Comment: Did you try rewriting the proof of their theorem 5 in the case the map is to a half open interval?

Comment: I failed. It looks like the proof only works for closed intervals.

Comment: Interesting. When I finish my other work I'll look around further.

Comment: I suspect completeness is the key. With completeness, I can prove $d_A(x)=d(a_x,x)$ for some $a_x\in A$